# If else statement for login page

Tags: magento-1.9

I can't figure out the code to identify the login page to implement an If Else statement.

If the current page = customer/account/login {Hide the footer div and the main navigation div}

Else {Show the footer div and the main navigation div}

Cheers in advance

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this using css (some may argue that this is not the best way but)

In your style.css

```
body.customer-account-login .footer, body.customer-account-login .top-header-nav {
   display:none;
}
```

*Please double check the class name above for `.footer` and `.top-header-nav`*

Answer (score 1):

With php you could detect the page with:

```
<?php   
$fullActionName = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName(); ?>

<?php if ($fullActionName == 'customer_account_login'): ?>
....
<?php endif; ?>
```